# libgl.so not found on Buildroot system with OpenGL

Tags: linux, opengl, embedded, buildroot, raspberry-pi4

I have trouble with adding OpenGL to my Buildroot system. When I add `mesa3d` with `OpenGL GLX` or `OpenGL ES` and some drivers (`Gallium KMSRO, v3d and vc4`) and try to run my app on builded system, I get error about missing libGL.so. So I thought, that I must add something else and added `libglu`.

I can't build my project with `libglu` because of following error:

```
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for GL... no
checking GL/gl.h usability... no
checking GL/gl.h presence... no
checking for GL/gl.h... no
configure: error: GL not found
make[1]: *** [package/pkg-generic.mk:240: /media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/build/libglu-9.0.1/.stamp_configured] Błąd 1
make: *** [Makefile:84: _all] Błąd 2
```

How to deal with it? It seems that this error and issue with running app have common ground.

Comment: Did you found the solution? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: I found solution or some workaround but now I don't remember much. In some cases helped runing `make clean all` instead of pure make.